How to pass credentials from AWS screte manager to docker file having conf.yaml file
I like to pass credentials from AWS screte manager to docker file having conf.yaml file, and my project structure explained below, How to pass the secrete manager credentials to conf file?
-src
|-dockerfile -> used to create image for ECS fargate
|-conf.yaml  -> copy conf files and having credentials to be filled with the credentials from AWS secrete manager
How to pass the secrete manager credentials to conf file?

You can retrieve Secrets Manager secrets through Amazon ECS environment variables.
Reference : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/secrets-envvar-secrets-manager.html
